# Computing the cohomology of the pair $(S^n\times S^n,D)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $D=(x,x)\subset S^n\times S^n$ be the diagonal, and assume $n$ is even.

> I need to prove that the following sequence (taken from l.e.s of the pair) is exact $$0 \rightarrow H^n(S^n\times S^n,D) \rightarrow H^n(S^n\times S^n) \rightarrow H^n(D) \rightarrow 0$$

**What I did:** Exactness on the left is clear, because $D$ is homeomorphic to the $n$-sphere and hence $H^{n-1}(D)\cong H^{n-1}(S^n)\cong 0$  (Thanks to user113969 for the confirmation)

I **don't** know how to prove exactness on the right. Cannot find a valid argument for showing that $H^n(S^n\times S^n)\to H^n(D)$ is surjective.

Comment: Yes the diagonal of a space $X$ is always homeomorphic to $X$ by the homeo : $x\mapsto (x,x)$ whose inverse is $(x,x)\mapsto x$. This should also help you to prove that the map $H^n(S^n\times S^n)\rightarrow H^n(D)$ is onto.

Comment: @user113969 do you have any argument for the surjectivity?

Comment: @LuigiM For the surjectivity, you can use the fact that the map $D\rightarrow S^n\times S^n$ has a retraction, hence the map in homology splits and is onto.